# Windows python ошибка OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument - datetime

Tags: windows, datetime, timestamp, python-3.9

Возникает ошибка в Windows(в линукс все работает как надо) - OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

```
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
a.timestamp() # - здесь возникает ошибка
```

Как это можно исправить в windows?

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то в каком-то проекте я использовал кроссплатформенный костыль, типа такого:

```py
def get_utc_timestamp(dt: datetime.datetime) -> float:
    return (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать другую версию питона. На английском SO [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42413443/8324991), что это баг в версии 3.6 на Windows.

Comment: Я использую версию python 3.9